# Blender Geometry Nodes to make a crater

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm learning Geometry Nodes and I'm trying to make a procedural crater or concentric ripple mesh (like a rock being dropped in the water makes). I can use the Cone node with 0 depth along with a number of side segments to create a circle tessellated with rings. This is the base shape I need.

Now for each edge loops of the collapsed cone, I then was thinking to use a profile spline to determine the Z offset of the vertices in a concentric edge loop. There might be other/better ways.

I can't figure out how to get the edge loops, or how to figure out the vertices indices in a circular mesh. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you put an Image in your question it will be easier to understand what you want exactly

Comment: and even better would be to provide a blend file with your test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you wanna start doing that by this node tree?

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. This is really helpful understanding an approach!

Comment: you are welcome